# Rails scope filter by date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

There are many questions relate to rails date range problem but mine is a little more complicated.

I have two models: house and booking. A House has_many bookings. A Booking has two attributes in date format: check_in and check_out.

What I want to achieve: Giving a valid date range, show all houses that are available during this range. In detail:

- The start date of the range should not be in any booking.
- The end date of the range should not be in any booking.
- There should not be any booking between the start and the end.

Can this be done using the rails scope?

**UPDATE:**

I found the code below that can check scope date interval that overlaps.

```
named_scope :overlapping, lambda { |interval| {
:conditions => ["id <> ? AND (DATEDIFF(start_date, ?) * DATEDIFF(?, end_date)) >= 0", interval.id, interval.end_date, interval.start_date]
}}
```

How can I transfer this to my problem?

Comment: You should probably use the [Bookable Gem](https://github.com/kunks001/bookable).

Comment: @AntarrByrd Thanks for the suggestion. I already have my own model and I want to keep it simple and just do the scope.

Comment: You could always have a look at how it is done [there](https://github.com/kunks001/bookable/blob/c641a73fbe006ebd30b60cf29a54b25fe2032f33/lib/bookable/generators/bookable/templates/models/bookable.rb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scope :overlapping, (lambda do |start_date, end_date|
  House.includes(:bookings).where("bookings.check_in < ? AND bookings.check_out > ?", 
  start_date, end_date).references(:bookings).uniq
end)
```

I went ahead and deleted the `>=` and `<=` operators in favor of `>` and `<` to explicitly show these bookings being outside of the given range, but you can adjust them per your needs!

**Update**

Changed query to use `#includes` instead of `#joins`, since we're querying the attached table.

Comment: Can you explain what the "references(:bookings)" does? I'm currently using code without this part and still testing.

Comment: Now I encounter with a problem that same house shows multiple times if several bookings meet the range requirement. For example, house 1 has 4 bookings. None of them overlaps with the given range. The result will be house 1 being listed for 4 times.

Comment: I've updated my answer to append a `#uniq` method to the scope, thus returning only uniq instances of any given house.

Comment: The code work perfectly after several test cases. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to have this query through scope. Put this scope in `house` model.

```
scope :overlapping, -> (start_date, end_date) { 
  includes(:bookings).where('bookings.check_in < ? AND bookings.check_out > ?',
  start_date.to_date, end_date.to_date)
}
```

And call as `House.overlapping('2015-07-01', '2015-07-09')`