# Search for date rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I search for the date in string format but the value in the database is integer example `December` which is 12-1-2017. I want to return all the dates which has the month of december
The format is `12-1-2017` but i output it in the view as `date.try(:strftime, "%B %d, %Y")`

Model

```
scope :search_query, lambda { |query|

  return nil  if query.blank?

  terms = query.downcase.split(/\s+/)

  terms = terms.map { |e|
    (e.gsub('*', '%') + '%').gsub(/%+/, '%')
  }

  num_or_conds = 2
  where(
    terms.map { |term|
      "(LOWER(reserve.date) LIKE ?)"
    }.join(' AND '),
    *terms.map { |e| [e] * num_or_conds }.flatten
  )
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to the call `Foo.search_query('December')` to return all foos which date is `2017-12-01` or which date is in the range from `2017-12-01` to `2017-12-31`? What should be returned for `search_query('January')` - this year's records or next year's?

Comment: what kind of query are you trying to do that you need to hack active record to the point that its difficult to read and understand. from what i read, you were asking how to query a date in string but it was stored as integer. are we talking about date time being stored as utc time integer?

Comment: @spickermann I want to call Foo.search_query('December') to return all foos with the month december in them and when the user types in the complete december 1, 2017 the user will only get all dates with december 1,2017, or if the user types 1 the user will get all dates with 1

Comment: Your dates in db are strings like '12-1-2017'? Sounds like you're looking for full-text search with synonym filters. You should consider using something like elasticsearch.

Comment: What does your `date` column has? Varchar? Date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you should build a [range query condition](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions)

The whole idea is, use the [ruby Date class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) to build the date object

```
Date.parse('December')
=> #<Date: 2017-12-01 ((2458089j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Experiment in your `irb` console all those methods that suit to your needs

As explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31013961/rails-scope-filter-by-date-range#31017789) from [Sajid Rabbani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5022651/sajid-rabbani) perform the query as a range. If the user want to have only one day, then you can set an `if` condition inside or use the same `start_date` and `end_date`

```
scope :date_range, -> (start_date, end_date) { 
  .where('reserve.date < ? AND reserve.date > ?',
  start_date.to_date, end_date.to_date)
}
```

I am not following all that formatting your wrote, but it is not really clear. If you want to write dry code, you can include a `method` in the `date` class

```
class Date
  def date_format
      # include your logic
  end
end
```